# Add headers to an exported Excel file

Tags: php, export-to-excel

I am using [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) to export results of a database query to Excel, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE BranchID=12345
```

And while I can export the row contents, I also (of course) want to have the column names.

The following code works out export the data:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once'PHPExcel.php';
$branchID=$_SESSION['ITEM'];
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE BranchID='$branchID' ORDER BY Type";
// Execute the database query
$result =sqlsrv_query($dbhandle, $SQL, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static'));

// Instantiate a new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Donor tracking System")
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("DTS")
                             ->setTitle("All members")
                             ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                             ->setDescription("All Members, generated using PHP classes.")
                             ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
                             ->setCategory("Test result file");

// Set the active Excel worksheet to sheet 0
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
// Initialise the Excel row number
$rowCount = 1;

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['Name']);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount,date_format( $row['dateOfreg'],"d-m-Y"));
    // Increment the Excel row counter
    $rowCount++;
} 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('All Members');

// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="allmembers.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

// Instantiate a Writer to create an OfficeOpenXML Excel .xlsx file
$objWriter =  PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
// Write the Excel file to filename some_excel_file.xlsx in the current directory
$objWriter->save('php://output');

exit;
?>
```

How do I add headers to the columns in the Excel file?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it make sense to just have an array with each column header and then write that to your file right before you start writing the rows your fetch from the SQL server?

Write the headers, increment your counter variable, and write the remaining rows.

Comment: If you read the documentation there are different ways you can do this, but perhaps it would be easiest to just do the following:  

  `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', "BranchID")->setCellValue('B1', "Type")->setCellValue('C1', "Item");`

  This would go right after you're setting the active sheet and before your row count variable. Then use `$rowCount = 2;` instead of 1.

  Docs: [link](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation).